# Jsf Edit functionality in a datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a bean with 5 properties.In which user has to enter the values and save the values.The saved values are displayed in a datatable by ajax functionality.It is working fine.The problem is when i want to edit the record, i have the edit button associated with every row of the table.When edit button is clicked i have to get the record and show the record in editable format above the datatable.What component i have to use to populate the data for editing ? Edit button is also an ajax request.I used panelGrid for that but i did not get them.
could you suggest the right way to solve this one.
Thank you all.........

Comment: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the same datatable for editing.

If you click edit button, store the selected value or index in the backing bean and

- render an output component like `h:outputText` if rowValue != selectedItem
- render an input component like `h:inputText` if rowValue == selectedItem

in your dataTable.

Here is an example:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.itemList}" var="item">
  <h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.someValue}" 
                  rendered="#{item != selectedItem}"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{item.someValue}" 
                 rendered="#{item == selectedItem}" />
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```